# creating a special view or function

Tags: sql, function, view

I have a table A (ID int, codeID int, sdate datetime, edate datetime, SID int)

I want to insert only those records in a view which have most recent edate for same codeID,

example

```
ID codeID sdate        edate        SID
1  23     2011-01-01   2012-01-01   123
2  25     2007-01-01   2008-04-05   234
3  25     2008-07-08   2009-05-05   258
4  28     2007-05-05   NULL         987
```

Now in view or function, I want only

```
ID codeID sdate        edate        SID
1  23     2011-01-01   2012-01-01   123
3  25     2008-07-08   2009-05-05   258
4  28     2007-05-05   NULL         987
```

because there is updated value for codeID 25 (expired however) but I still want it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from A a1
where not exists (select 1 from A a2 where a1.codeID = a2.codeID and a2.edate > a1.edate)
```

See it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca773/2).